# Error PHP to Twig converter when use unserialize

Tags: php, twig

```
<?php 
$banner_categories = unserialize($bi['categories']); 
?>
```

When convert to twig template

```
{% set banner_categories = unserialize(bi['categories']) %}
```

Show error: Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "unserialize" function in ...

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to call even native PHP functions from a Twig template.

You need to write a Twig extension:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Or use this [Twig PHP Function extension](https://github.com/umpirsky/twig-php-function) that allows you to call native PHP functions: